# Different behavior in runBlocking<Unit> vs runBlockingTest

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Sample 1:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testExceptionInAsync() = runBlockingTest {
        var foundException = false

        val job = async<Boolean> {
            delay(500)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Crash nach 500ms")
        }

        try {
            job.await()
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            logger.info("Found Exception! (testExceptionInAsync/${e})")
            foundException = true
        }

        assertThat(foundException).isTrue
        assertThat(job.isCancelled).isTrue
    }
```

Sample 2:

```kotlin
    @Test
    fun testExceptionInAsync() = runBlocking<Unit> {
        var foundException = false

        val job = async<Boolean> {
            delay(500)
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Crash nach 500ms")
        }

        try {
            job.await()
        } catch (e: IllegalArgumentException) {
            logger.info("Found Exception! (testExceptionInAsync/${e})")
            foundException = true
        }

        assertThat(foundException).isTrue
        assertThat(job.isCancelled).isTrue
    }
```

Sample 1 crashes but Sample 2 works as expected - shouldn't these two examples behave the same way????

Comment: @Gustavo It crashes with IllegalArgumentException

Comment: Can't reproduce. Sample 2 throws `IllegalArgumentException` too.

Comment: Sure - sample 2 also throws the exception but does not crash the test but sample1 does

Answer (score 2):

`runBlockingTest` is pretty much the same as `runBlocking`, with the exception that runBlockingTest will skip delays.

What I believe is happening in your tests `runBlocking` waits for the delay function to finish causing a time out. `runBlockingTest` is skipping the delay function allowing the test to pass.

The testing code lab 5.3 recommends using runBlocking for testing doubles.

Comment: The link you provided is an Amazon product! Please reconsider it. Thanks.